# Overwriting PHP Binary but .profile doesn't exist?

Tags: php, macos, overwrite

On http://php-osx.liip.ch/ it says
php-osx doesn't overwrite the php binaries installed by Apple, but installs everything in /usr/local/php5. The new php binary is therefore in `/usr/local/php5/bin/php`.

You can also adjust your `PATH` do include that directory, eg. write into your `~/.profile` file the following

`export PATH="/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH"` but when I goto `~` I don't see a `.profile` even when I run defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES to show the hidden files

Comment: .bashrc? you need to check for the startup file for whatever shell you're using, which may NOT use .profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check which shell you are using by opening a terminal and entering following command:

```
echo $SHELL
```

- If it prints `/bin/zsh` then you can add your export to the end of `~/.zshrc` file.
- If it prints `/bin/bash` or `/usr/local/bin/bash` you can use `~/.bashrc`.
- But if it is another shell check corresponding shell's configuration file.

Normally you can create the profile file yourself and shells would read it if it exists.

Comment: I got /bin/bash but there is no .bashrc file? I only see a .bash_history

Comment: In that case can you enter `touch ~/.profile` and edit `~/.profile` file? It should be loaded automatically normally once created.